# Google Material Icons, Outlined, Rounded, Two-Tone, Sharp sets are not working

Tags: icons, material-design, webfonts, google-webfonts

I'm trying to use the [Material Icons font from Google Outlined set](https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=outline) that just came out, but I can't figure it out. There is no information nor documentation.
Some icons are being displayed as filled and some as outlined.

eg: The `account_circle` icon from the **[Outlined set](https://material.io/tools/icons/?search=account%20circ&icon=account_circle&style=outline)**

**How are you supposed to use the Outlined set?** Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you have reason when switch the ***Filled style*** option to ***Outline style*** don't change all icons appearance. Example: [Filled icons](https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=accessible&style=baseline) //\\  [Outlined icons](https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=accessible&style=outline)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

---

### Update as of 2021

In short Google isn't (still) advertising the fact that you can load the different set via the Google API url on the Material Icons website. They are only, as per [Google Material Icons instructions](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#setup-method-1-using-via-google-web-fonts), talking about the default filled set which uses the following `html` tag to enqueue the Material Icons base `stylesheet`.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

If you want to use the Outlined, the Two Tone, Round or Sharp sets, you need to add the following to the Material Icons url.

| Theme | URL parameters | CSS class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Filled** *(Default)* | `?family=Material+Icons` | `material-icons` |
| **Outlined** | `?family=Material+Icons+Outlined` | `material-icons-outlined` |
| **Two Tone** | `?family=Material+Icons+Two+Tone` | `material-icons-two-tone` |
| **Round** | `?family=Material+Icons+Round` | `material-icons-round` |
| **Sharp** | `?family=Material+Icons+Sharp` | `material-icons-sharp` |

---

### Better performances

Like Google text-based font, Google Material Icons also accept the `&display=swap` url parameter.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Two+Tone&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

You can learn more about `&display=swap` @ https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/02/font-display

You can also specify a `<link rel="preconnect"` tag in the `<head>` of your document to improve load performances.

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
```

---

### Example

```html
<!--head-->
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Two+Tone&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<!--body-->
<span class="material-icons-two-tone">
account_circle
</span>
<span class="material-icons-two-tone">
check_circle
</span>
<span class="material-icons-two-tone">
favorite
</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

Update, with Answer:

Looking at the Readme in the source code, https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages/material-ui-icons

You Append Outline to the icon name. So for you:

```
import { AccountCircleOutline } from "@material-ui/icons";
```

or

```
import AccountCircleOutline from "@material-ui/icons/AccountCircleOutline";
```

I do believe this answers your question. A "correct answer" is always nice! Thanks!